# C# - Crear un Setup para un Servicio Windows con Timer

Tags: c#, .net, windows, servicio

Recientemente he creado un servicio windows con *System.Timers.Timer*, este servicio cumplirá una tarea de crear un archivo **.txt** cada minuto (1 minuto).

**PROBLEMA**

Luego de crear su Setup(instalador) y pueda instalar en mi propia PC o en otra PC. El problema está en que no cumple con su tarea de crear un **.txt** cada minuto. Alguien que me pueda corregir si es la manera de crear un servicio con timer en la siguiente estructura.

**ESTRUCTURA**

CLASS:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.ServiceProcess;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Timers;

namespace GEN_FE_WS
{
    public partial class GEN_FE_WS : ServiceBase
    {
        Timer timer;

        public GEN_FE_WS()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
        {
            this.timer = new System.Timers.Timer(1000D);//1000 MILISEGUNDOS O 1 MINUTO
            this.timer.AutoReset = true;
            this.timer.Elapsed += new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(this.timer_Elapsed);
            this.timer.Start();
        }

        protected override void OnStop()
        {
            this.timer.Stop();
            this.timer = null;
        }

        private void timer_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            ServiceCrear();
        }

        public static void ServiceCrear()
        { 
              //Aquí creará el TXT

        }
    }
}
```

PROGRAM.CS :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.ServiceProcess;
using System.Text;

namespace GEN_FE_WS
{
    static class Program
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// The main entry point for the application.
        /// </summary>
        static void Main()
        {
            ServiceBase[] ServicesToRun;
            ServicesToRun = new ServiceBase[] 
            { 
                new GEN_FE_WS() 
            };
            ServiceBase.Run(ServicesToRun);
        }
    }
}
```

**¿Cuándo haces debug de tu servicio de Windows funciona y crea el archivo .txt?**

Si, solo requiere de un poco de cambios en la *estructura*.

AGREGAMOS - CLASS :

```
 public void OnDebug()
        {
            OnStart(null);
        }
```

EDITAMOS - PROGRAMA.CS:

```
  static void Main()
        {

          GEN_FE_WS myService = new GEN_FE_WS();
          myService.OnDebug();  
          System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(System.Threading.Timeout.Infinite);
        }
```

**SOLUCIÓN**

Desconozco los problemas internos de mi PC, lo reinicie y funciona como se espera. Para eso, he puesto un nuevo método para que me notifique por el *Visor de Eventos* que es lo que esta sucediendo con el Servicio Windows. 
Aquí lo tienen:

```
static void WriteEventLogEntry(string message)
        {
            // Create an instance of EventLog
            System.Diagnostics.EventLog eventLog = new System.Diagnostics.EventLog();

            // Check if the event source exists. If not create it.
            if (!System.Diagnostics.EventLog.SourceExists("Generador txt"))
            {
                System.Diagnostics.EventLog.CreateEventSource("Generador FAC.ELE.", "Application");
            }

            // Set the source name for writing log entries.
            eventLog.Source = "Generador txt";

            // Create an event ID to add to the event log
            int eventID = 8;

            // Write an entry to the event log.
            eventLog.WriteEntry(message,
                                System.Diagnostics.EventLogEntryType.Warning,
                                eventID);

            // Close the Event Log
            eventLog.Close();

        }
```

**CONCLUSIÓN**

Ya genera los archivos .txt cada minuto y espero que este foro sirva como guía para muchos que quieran crear un Instalador de Servicio Windows con Timer. 
Saludos y gracias a @Flxtr por su colaboración y dedicación.

Comment: ¿Cuándo haces `debug` de tu servicio de Windows funciona y crea el archivo *.txt*?

Comment: ¿En dónde se muestra ese error? ¿Al crear el instalador agregaste todos los archivos de la carpeta `bin` al instalador?

Comment: Uso el VisualStudio 2013, he descargado el 'Microsoft Visual Studio 2013 Installer Projects ' y realizo los siguientes pasos:
1. File System : Agrego en la carpeta "Application Folder" un ProyectOutput, selecciono mi proyecto como "Primary Output", Configuration como "Active" (Claro que en mi proyecto esta seleccionado el modo RELEASE) y acepto.
2. Luego en el panel de "Custom Action" agrego un custom action en las carpetas(Install y Uninstall).
3. Compilo.

Comment: Cabe resaltar que he creado en mi service windows un "ProjectInstaller" para el servicio que será creado al momento de instalar e inicializada.
Propiedades del ProjectInstaller(como LocalSystem y de manera Automatic)

Comment: Excelente, me parece que solo falta un paso más: abre el proyecto y en la carpeta `Application Folder` agrega una carpeta llamada `bin`, dentro de la carpeta `bin` agrega todos los archivos de la carpeta `bin` que se generan cuando compilas tu proyecto, realmente faltan las DLLs con las que tu servicio debe funcionar, una vez realizado esto, vuelve a compilar tu proyecto para que se genere un nuevo instalador, reinstalas y listo :)

Comment: Entonces solo agregaria en esa carpeta bin solo los de formato .dll ?

Comment: Si generaste tu proyecto en modo Release solo serían las DLLs, pero a modo de realizar la primer prueba agrega todos los archivos de la carpeta `bin`

Comment: He realizado como mencionaste pero sigue igual.

Comment: ¿Tu servicio aparece como *Iniciado* en la lista de los servicios? Esto lo puedes encontrar dando tecla `[Windows] + [R]` (Se abre cuadro de dialogo de `Ejecutar`) luego teclea `services.msc` y dale `[Enter]`, se enlistan todos los servicios, busca por nombre el que hayas instalado y revisa si se encuentra inicializado

Comment: Si, aparece en la lista y esta iniciada.